# Build environments for PHP extensions?

Tags: php, delphi, php-extension

Looking for development frameworks for creating custom PHP Extensions. [PHP4Delphi](http://users.telenet.be/ws36637/php4delphi.html) looks promising. And there's the usual Visual Studio route. Are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

I use simple text editor (EditPlus) and Windows SDK for developing i.e. edit the extension and `nmake`.